# Text from standard input not visible after program exits from a readline

Tags: linux, terminal, tty, c, readline

I am facing an issue where the text from my stdin is not visible from on my terminal. My program does the following

Sets a SIGALRM handler which exits a program when there is no input from the user after certain duration.

```c
void sigalrm_handler(int arg)
{   
    exit(0);
}
```

In main function :

```c
{
...
alarm(100);
line = readline(line = readline(prompt);)
...
}
```

However, after my program exits, I cannot see what I type on my terminal. But the commands work fine.

running 
`system("reset")` solves the issue for now. But I need a cleaner solution.
I have tried 
`int rl_reset_line_state ()` and `int rl_reset_terminal (char *terminal_name)` but they dont seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern shells tend to restore the terminal state after the exit of a program; older or less capable shells may not, as you observe. The usual approach as seen in APUE and other texts is to save a copy of the terminal state using `tcgetattr`, then restore that state when the program exits:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

struct itimerval Alarm_Timer;
struct termios Original_Termios;
int Need_Reset;

void sigalrm_handler(int arg)
{
    if (Need_Reset)
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &Original_Termios);
    exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *line;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &Original_Termios);
    Need_Reset = 1;

    signal(SIGALRM, sigalrm_handler);
    Alarm_Timer.it_value.tv_sec = 3;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &Alarm_Timer, NULL);

    line = readline("* ");

    if (Need_Reset)
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &Original_Termios);

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `libreadline` is installing its own signal handlers for `ALRM`, `INT`, etc. and will exit just fine (after restoring the termios/stty settings) upon receiving such a signal.

You can check by running/stracing a simple program like this:

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
        alarm(3); readline("foo> ");
}
```

So you could just get rid of your signal handler.

Second, you should **never** call `exit(3)` from a signal handler. `exit(3)`, unlike the `_exit(2)` system call, is **not** signal safe, mainly because it has to run the handlers registered with `atexit(3)`. For instance, just think what happens if the `exit(3)` is invoked while another `exit(3)` is already running through those handlers.

If instead of using `readline(3)` you're using your own code which puts the terminal into raw mode, etc, you should always save the state of the terminal upon starting **and** upon receiving a `SIGCONT` signal, and restore it before exiting **and** upon receiving a `SIGTSTP` signal. Not just on starting/exiting as seen in a lot of examples. And if you're using cursor addressing, you should also turn on/off the `ca_mode` with the `smcup` / `rmcup` escapes when saving/restoring the termios settings.